# How can I install a two disk game with Wine?

Tags: wine, games, software-installation

I would like to install Medieval II : Total War under wine. Everything goes well until I am prompted to install the second dvd-rom to finish the install.

No matter what path I supply to the installer it says setup can't find a file on the specified path or disk. I've tried the options shown for D and Z drives, /dev/sr0, /media/myname etc.

I've also had similar problems with Medal of Honour.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In the case of StarCraft, the installer just looks for the "Tome" files, copy the first cd to a directory, and copy the second cd's files to the same directory. This worked for me fine; this won't work for games that use the same file name on all cd's, but maybe you could overwrite the directory with the next cd's file as the installer goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Wine, you must enter BOTH discs before launching the installation, because Wine only reads what was already mounted when it started. It's the same reasoning when you change a program's configuration file (like .js, .ini, or whatever that's is not in the GUI options), it has to be restarted to apply the changes.

**Solution 1)** Insert both discs then launch the installation.

**Solution 2)** If you have only one disc-tray (or cd-drive), or if you don't want to restart the installation :

- Create a new directory somewhere (I'll name it DISC2 but you do what you want):

  `mkdir ~/DISC2`
- Copy the CD's content into the new directory with drag-and-drop or commandline (replace /path/to/cd by the path to your mounted CD):

  `cp -r /path/to/cd ~/DISC2`
- Under Wine, point the DISC-2 path to `~/DISC2`

Comment: I've tried that but get errors copying because it is a 'read only file' system and permission is denied. I suppose that is another question entirely.

Comment: Uh, read-only or not, you should be able to copy the files into your hard-drive. 

Open Nautilus as root ( `gksu nautilus` )and retry the copy.

Comment: No, it won't work. I obviously have some other problem beside what I originally thought.

Comment: you can try **`rm -r ~/DISC2`**, then **`sudo mkdir ~/DISC2`**, then **`sudo cp -rf /path/to/cd ~/DISC2`**.

Comment: It's ok now. For some reason the fact that a different dvd was in the drive had not been registered - even after logout! After a fresh start, I did as you suggested and it worked fine, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 CDs, then copy each image/CD into a folder separately and name them 'a' and 'b' (for simplicity). After configuring your wine wrapper, install the game normally and select the setup file in 'a'. When the installer prompts you for the second CD, just change 'a' to 'b' and that should do. Hope it helps :).